# Flash and the JavaScript working directory

Tags: javascript, flash

I use javascript to play a flash file, and it plays correctly. But it also needs to parse some configuration files in the flash default directory. So the problem is: the flash file I am going to play can't access its config file for the wrong working directory.

For example, I specify the swf path value as 'falsh/list/test.swf', so my javascript will give this swf value by `swfobject.embedSWF` to play this flash. But the flash file `flash/list/test.swf` needs to parse a config file in the same directory with flash file like `flash/list/config.xml`. The problem is flash attempts to parse this config file under the current javascript working directory.

I've searched a lot, but haven't found a way to resolve this; can anyone help?

```
var name = parse_parameter('name');
var path = parse_parameter('path');
var swf = path+"/"+name+".swf";
swfobject.embedSWF(swf, "myContent", "800", "500", "9.0.0");
```

Comment: Forgot to say, my working environment is linux, i have found that activeX can resolve this under windows. but haven't found out a way under linux

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit vague, if you just want to find the working directory of the active thread you need to know a few things, namely a filename to look for.  JS does not know where it comes from, however theres some tricks to finding a working directory.  There's many implementations of this, I will copy what leaflet has done to find it's current directory.

https://github.com/CloudMade/Leaflet/blob/master/src/Leaflet.js

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
    for (var i = 0, len = scripts.length; i < len; i++) {
        var src = scripts[i].src,
            res = src && src.match(/^(.*\/)leaflet-*\w*\.js.*$/);
        if (res && res[1]) { return res[1]; }
    }
    return '../../dist/';
```

The above looks for a script with name containing leaflet, then figures out the directory from the script src field.

Best of luck,

Comment: Sorry for that confused you. My quesiont is not going to find the working directory. i want to find a way to change the javascript working directory(seems javascript can't do this.) or change flash working directory. For example my javascript is nuder /home/play.js .And will going to play flash under /home/flash/flash.swf. and this flash.swf need to parse the file config.xml under /home/falsh/condig.xml . problem is when flash.swf to parse file config.xml, it will going to directory /home/ to find the file config.xml which is js working directory.